# ms-settings, easeofaccess-cursorandpointersize and others don't work in Windows 10, 22H2

Tags: windows, powershell, uri, settings

Unfortunately, a lot of searching didn't help. There are many lists online, of URIs to the different Windows settings.

You can start them e.g. in PowerShell by:

```
Start ms-settings:easeofaccess-cursorandpointersize
```

But none of them work anymore. I know they did. I don't know how long it was agon, but they worked. But not in the current Windows 10 22H2.If you run, e.g., the above PowerShell command line, the Windows settings open, but always on the settings homepage. And the same for all other ways of starting and URIs.
Any Ideas? Are there new, secret URIs. Or is it just deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ms-settings:` URI scheme is documented in [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app):

As of Windows 11, the following works, per the [Ease of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#ease-of-access) section:

```
start ms-settings:easeofaccess-mousepointer
```

Note:

- On Windows, `start` is PowerShell's built-in alias for its [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet.
- Since `start` is also the name of the comparable internal `cmd.exe` command, the above works from `cmd.exe` / batch files too.
- As you state, if the specific URI path (such as `easeofaccess-mousepointer`) isn't recognized, it is *quietly ignored*:

  - If the Settings app wasn't running, it opens and shows its home page.
  - If it was already running, the existing window is simply *activated* (and therefore shows whatever page happens to be the current one).